# Условный тернарный оператор в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
idVhod.style.display = (idVhod.style.display == 'inline') ? '' : 'inline';
```

Как именно работает условный тернарный оператор в JavaScript? Какое значение присваивается свойству *display* ?

Comment: Это тернарный оператор https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Answer (score 0):

Здесь использован тернарный оператор "если"

```
(idVhod.style.display == 'inline') ? '' : 'inline';
```

Если описать смысл то это выглядит вот так:

```
// если у элемента idVhod css стиль дисплей равен инлайн
if (idVhod.style.display == 'inline'){
  // сбросим css стиль дисплей до его значения по умолчанию
  idVhod.style.display = '';
}
else{
  // Иначе установим css стиль дисплей в инлайн
  idVhod.style.display = 'inline';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как @Andrei и сказал, это тернарный оператор, но вообще это конструкция:

```
(idVhod.style.display == 'inline') ? '' : 'inline';
```

Эквивалентна:

```
(function() {
  if(idVhod.style.display == 'inline') {
    return ''
  }

  return 'inline'
})();
```

То есть, получается такой код:

```
idVhod.style.display = (function() {
  if(idVhod.style.display == 'inline') { // если idVhod имеет CSS свойство display, равную inline, тогда
    return '' // вернуть пустую строку (то есть убрать свойство display)
  }

  return 'inline' // иначе, возвращаем inline
})();
```

#### Как работает условный тернарный оператор?

Сначала мы пишем условие, потом знак `?`, после него, то что мы должны дать, если условие выполнилось. После, **обязательно** пишем `:`, ну и соответственно после этого знака пишем то, что должно вернутся если условие не сработало, то есть синтаксис какой-то такой:

```
условие ? ответЕслиУсловиеСработало : ответЕслиУсловиеНеСработало
```

**Внимание**, в отличие от `if (...) { ... } else { ... }`, мы не можем просто взять и убрать `else { ... }`, в условном тернарном операторе всегда должно быть значение которое вернётся, если условие не сработает.

#### Так что же делает строка?

Строка меняет свойство `display`, у элемента `idVhod`, если на данный свойство равно `inline`, тогда `display` в принципе убирается из стилей (CSS свойство в JavaScript, можно убрать из стилей, если ему присвоить пустую строку), если же `display` не равен `inline`'у, тогда его делают `inline`'ом, вот так вот всё просто.

Материал по теме:

- [Условный (тернарный) оператор](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)
- [Тернарная условная операция](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)
- [Тернарные операторы](https://pavel-karateev.gitbook.io/intermediate-python/sintaksis/ternary_operators)
- [Условный оператор „?“](https://learn.javascript.ru/ifelse#uslovnyy-operator)
- [Тернарный оператор (условный оператор Javascript).](https://stackdev.blog/blog/ifelse)

Comment: property !== proportion ;-)

Comment: @UModeL спасибо что упомянули :))